# MSSQL container fails to start when mapping volumes after upgrading to WSL2

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop, wsl-2

After I changed Docker Desktop to use WSL2, I am unable to start an mssql image using Docker-compose.

If I don't map the volumes the container starts up.

**Docker-compose**

```
services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    container_name: mssql
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "***********"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
    - 1433:1433
    volumes:
    - ~/docker/sql/mssql/:/var/opt/mssql/
    - ~/docker/sql/sqlserver/:/var/opt/sqlserver/
    healthcheck:
      test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P "$$SA_PASSWORD" -Q "SELECT 1" || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

**Error**

```
** ERROR: [AppLoader] Failed to load LSA: 0xc0070102
AppLoader: Exiting with status=0xc0070102
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Tue Dec 15 13:49:34 2020
The following diagnostic information is available:

Reason: 0x00000006
Message: Termination of \SystemRoot\system32\AppLoader.exe was due to fatal error 0xC0000001
Address: 0x3fffb0c551f1
Stack Trace:
file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000030E7D9
file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000030C769
file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000255F1D
file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x00000000002551F1
file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000254A72
file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000254B4B
file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000202FE2
file://package4/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000347898
file:///windows/system32/AppLoader.exe+0x0000000000003C90
file:///Windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL+0x0000000000014414
file:///windows/system32/ntdll.dll+0x0000000000075541
<unknown>+0x00000000FC3FE000
Process: 10 - sqlservr
Thread: 39 (application thread 0x68)
Instance Id: 7cfc9545-c829-4a7e-a461-83b481fe05e3
Crash Id: b747c621-d4e2-46ed-9122-f14a8d54386a
Build stamp: fd4eb1565f159d8f4b2d49c48e96d5797508c8bc5f222def3def149a28435962
Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Processors: 8
Total Memory: 13339308032 bytes
Timestamp: Tue Dec 15 13:49:34 2020

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
/bin/cat: /proc/10/maps: Permission denied
/bin/cat: /proc/10/environ: Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: '/proc/10/map_files': Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: '/proc/10/map_files': Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: '/proc/10/map_files': Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: '/proc/10/map_files': Permission denied
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin/timeout: failed to run command '/bin/journalctl': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/timeout: failed to run command '/bin/journalctl': No such file or directory
Tue Dec 15 13:49:36 UTC 2020 Capturing program information
Tue Dec 15 13:49:36 UTC 2020 Attempting to capture a dump with paldumper for pid 10
WARNING: Capture attempt failure detected
Attempting to capture a filtered dump with paldumper for pid 10
WARNING: Attempt to capture dump failed. Reference /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.10.temp/log/paldumper-debug.log for details

Tue Dec 15 13:49:36 UTC 2020 Attempting to capture a dump with gdb
Tue Dec 15 13:49:36 UTC 2020 Captured a dump with gdb
Tue Dec 15 13:49:36 UTC 2020 Capturing program binaries
Tue Dec 15 13:49:36 UTC 2020 Compressing the dump files
```

**wsl --list --verbose**

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04           Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

Comment: Where is "Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS" coming into this? [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) is supposed to be 16.04 and your WSL has been updated to 20.04.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash#persist) states, the entire /var/opt/mssql folder cannot be mapped, but probably what you want is to map the data subdirectory /var/opt/mssql/data, which holds the db files, those you can map without any trouble

> ...Host volume mapping for Docker on Windows does not currently support mapping the complete /var/opt/mssql directory. However, you can map a subdirectory, such as /var/opt/mssql/data to your host machine...

Comment: Yeah, I found out the hard way. Should've posted my findings :(

Comment: This was the answer to a multi-hour issue. Thanks.

Comment: changed to /data as you said and it is working now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a problem with permissions. I had a similar issue where an MS SQL container couldn't initiate and keep crashing. That was solved by adding `user: root` so that container runs the server's user with root privilege. Have you tried this?

```yaml
services:
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    container_name: mssql
    user: root
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "***********"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
    - 1433:1433
    volumes:
    - ~/docker/sql/mssql/:/var/opt/mssql/
    - ~/docker/sql/sqlserver/:/var/opt/sqlserver/
    healthcheck:
      test: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P "$$SA_PASSWORD" -Q "SELECT 1" || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
```

PS: Some may have a security concern when running the server as root. Please chip in if you know how to handle this, though the [root privilege seems to be accepted by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-security?view=sql-server-ver16#run-the-non-root-container-as-the-root-user).